# php polymorphism - Call a parent function in polymorphed child function

Tags: php, object, polymorphism

Here's the parent class:

```
    class Event {

    public function getLang($lang){
     $sql = "select * from Event where EventID =" . $this->EventID . "AND Lang =" . $lang;
    $result = $this->selectOneRow($sql);
    }
}
```

and here's the child:

```
class Invitation extends Event{

public function getLang($lang){
Event::getLang($lang);

$sql = "select * from invitation where EventID =" . $this->EventID . " and Lang = " . $lang;

    }
}
```

I had some hope that EVENT::getLang($lang) would work but after I echo the query, I can see that it stops short of an EventID.

Is there a right way to do this?

I tried copy/pasting the code in the child directly but that can't work either because, I got variables at the parent's level to which the result of event's select will be assigned.

Is there any way to work around this or am I in a gridlock?

Comment: You seem to have a space missing before the "AND" in the $sql string in Event::getLang()

Comment: I just typed a quick short version of my code. I'm afraid the complete version would scare people off from answering! Just a typo. Thanks though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking to use the `parent` keyword:

```
class Invitation extends Event{
    public function getLang($lang){
       parent::getLang($lang);

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM invitation WHERE EventID =" . $this->EventID . " AND Lang = " . $lang;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked. I have another problem also related to polymorphism >< see you there!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `parent`

```
class Invitation extends Event{

    public function getLang($lang){
        parent::getLang($lang);
        ....
    }
}
```

`Event::getLang($lang);` is infact trying to call `getLang` statically.  See these links:

[Scope Resolution Operator (::)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

[Parent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php)

Answer (score 0):

The method is not static, so instead of calling the static method `Event::getLang()`, you need to call parents method

```
parent::getlang($lang);
```

Update:
I meant, with `Event::getLang()` you usually call a static method on a class, that may or may not be extended. Where `parent::method()` calls always the inherited method and keeps the scope (class or static) of the calling method, `Classname::method()` always tries to call a static method on the specific class.

Comment: You can actually use `parent::` in a static parent/child class setup

Comment: Right. I meant, with `Event::getLang()` you call a static method on an class, that may a parent class, or a completely different one. Of course you can call inherited static methods this way too, but `self::getLang()` is prefered here.